# best way to use video viewer. and play videos

Tags: android, android-videoview

Is there any way I can play a video that has been stored in the raw file, without the use of the uri. If not how do i properly set the uri. Let's say i have file named movie and I want to play it with a videoviewer. How would i do this? Also would i have to write the data to the sd card. or can i just play it from the raw.

Why cant I just do

```
uri uri.parse("android.resources://"+this.getApplicationContext().getPackageName()+movie);
```

This is what I have it as now if you could can you point out the errors to me so i know and i wont have to have this problem any more

```
          VideoView videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView1);
          videoview.setKeepScreenOn(true);
          videoview.setVideoPath("android.raw://com.example.movievp8");
          MediaController controller = new MediaController(videoview.getContext()); 
          videoview.setMediaController(controller);           
          videoview.start();
          videoview.requestFocus();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is something that works for me:

```
  videoResource = R.raw.some_video;
  String uri = String.format("android.resource://%s/%d", context.getPackageName(), videoResource);
  animationCanvas = (VideoView) ui.findViewById(R.id.animation_canvas);
  animationCanvas.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  animationCanvas.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri));
  animationCanvas.setOnCompletionListener(this);
  animationCanvas.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
      public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
          animationCanvas.start();

      }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks @Ravi ... for some reason the formatting was refusing to work